# how to unmarshal the json to get the below desired result

Tags: json, go

I have a json, that I am loading from a source. The contents of json is as below:

```
[{
    "name": "Develop",
    "path": "/develop",
    "color": "#E34D20",
    "icon": "DevelopIcon",
    "filter":{
      "permission.IsAdmin":true
    }
  }]
```

The required object in my golang code is as below:

```
{
    Name:  "Develop",
    Path:  "/develop",
    Color: "#E34D20",
    Icon:  "DevelopIcon",
    Filter: &FilterCondition{
        Permissions: map[string]bool{
            "IsAdmin": permissions.Role == "admin",
        },
    },
}
```

to achieve it in im golang code I am writing as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type FilterCondition struct {
    Permissions map[string]bool `json:"permission"`
}

type Item struct {
    Name   string           `json:"name"`
    Path   string           `json:"path"`
    Color  string           `json:"color"`
    Icon   string           `json:"icon"`
    Filter *FilterCondition `json:"filter"`
}

    func main() {
        // Read the JSON file
        data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("file.json")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    
        // Unmarshal the JSON into an array of Items
        var items []Item
        err = json.Unmarshal(data, &items)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    
        // Print each item
        for _, item := range items {
            fmt.Printf("Name: %s\nPath: %s\nColor: %s\nIcon: %s\nFilter: %v\n\n", item.Name, item.Path, item.Color, item.Icon, item.Filter)
        }
    }
```

But the output that I am getting contains

```
Name: Develop
Path: /develop
Color: #E34D20
Icon: DevelopIcon
Filter: &{map[]}
```

instead of

```
{
    Name:  "Develop",
    Path:  "/develop",
    Color: "#E34D20",
    Icon:  "DevelopIcon",
    Filter: &FilterCondition{
        Permissions: map[string]bool{
            "IsAdmin": permissions.Role == "admin",
        },
    },
}
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: Use  field`Filter map[string]bool `json:"filter"` to match the structure of the data.  Write code to translate `map[string]bool{"permission.IsAdmin":true}` to your desired FilterCondition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot `.` in the name of a field of a JSON object bears no special semantics as far as `encoding/json` machinery is concerned (it also has no special meaning as per [the JSON spec](https://json.org)), so you need to implement custom JSON unmarshaling.

If I guessed the actual requirements correctly–the `Permissions` field of the resulting field of type `FilterCondition` must only contain the keys starting with the prefix "permission.", with that prefix stripped,–one approach could be this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

const data = `[{
    "name": "Develop",
    "path": "/develop",
    "color": "#E34D20",
    "icon": "DevelopIcon",
    "filter":{
      "permission.IsAdmin":true
    }
  }]`

type FilterCondition struct {
    Permissions map[string]bool `json:"permission"`
}

func (fc *FilterCondition) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var m map[string]bool

    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &m); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if len(m) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    fc.Permissions = make(map[string]bool)
    for k, v := range m {
        const permPrefix = "permission."
        if !strings.HasPrefix(k, permPrefix) {
            continue
        }
        fc.Permissions[k[len(permPrefix):]] = v
    }

    return nil
}

type Item struct {
    Name   string           `json:"name"`
    Path   string           `json:"path"`
    Color  string           `json:"color"`
    Icon   string           `json:"icon"`
    Filter *FilterCondition `json:"filter"`
}

func main() {
    var items []Item
    if err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(data)).Decode(&items); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, item := range items {
        fmt.Printf("Name: %s\nPath: %s\nColor: %s\nIcon: %s\nFilter: %v\n\n", item.Name, item.Path, item.Color, item.Icon, item.Filter)
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/46sV4n2-Wos).)